# No gray timepicker to use on Django template

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

I am placing the Jquery code for no gray time picker.

```
<input id="my_timepicker_input" name="my_timepicker_input" type="text">

<script type="text/javascript" src="ng_all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ng_ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="components/timepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   ng.ready( function() {
     var my_timepicker = new ng.TimePicker({
       input:'my_timepicker_input'
     });    
   });
</script>
```

This code is work in HTML input. When i have integrated it with django template the same shows nothing.

Image showing timepicker in html page

[image]

when I have used with django it shows only a text box. Not showing the visual clock in the above picture.

Please help me... I don't know anything about jquery. I just want to set time in the web page for alarm.

Comment: do you get any errors in the developers console of your browser?

Comment: Yes i got "ng is not defined".   what i have include for avoiding the error?

Comment: I think you need AngularJS

Comment: What is angularJS? why it is required?

Comment: You don't need Angular JS. I think @MihaiZamfir is saying that because Angular also uses an `ng` namespace, as does the No Gray JS library. From your error message, it sounds like Django is not serving your static files correctly. Have you looked at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development?

Comment: nimasmi, i have included ng_all.js , ng_ui.js and timepicker.js.  What i have to include extra.

Comment: Most probably you haven't included them correctly. They are not correctly served by Django, but they work locally because you have them in the same directory

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Now its worked when static files are included in the static folder